# Casperjs thenClick opens datepicker, but cannot retrieve anything inside the calendar

Tags: javascript, xpath, datepicker, phantomjs, casperjs

I am trying to scrape date information from a jQuery UI Datepicker calendar.

The calendar has a couple of days that have clickable links.

I want those links.

The calendar works fine for humans on the web site, but CasperJS cannot access the data in it, even though `casper.thenClick(...the xpath to the calendar...)` actually opens the calendar.

I mean, I can view the empty calendar by doing a `casper.capture(...)`.

Using Chrome, I can find the XPaths that I need, no problem.

**Why can't I make CasperJS get the data in the datepicker calendar?**

Here is the code:

```js
var casper = require('casper').create();
var utils = require('utils');
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;
casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.2) Gecko/20110201');

casper.start('http://www.hawaiifoodtours.com/north-shore-food-tour/');

casper.then(function() {
    // Click on 1st result link
    this.click('#date_a6130');
    console.log('clicked on calendar');
});

casper.wait(1000, function(){
    casper.capture('theCalendar.png');
    // this is the XPath Chrome gives me. No problem. 
    var stuff = casper.getElementsInfo(x('//*[@id="dp1444234738328"]/div/table/tbody'));
    utils.dump(stuff);
});

casper.run();
```

I'm adding error messages based on the advice of Artjom B.:

```
ResourceError: {
    "errorCode": 2,
    "errorString": "Connection closed",
    "url": "https://www.hawaiifun.org/reservation/common/jquery/css/ui-lightness-1.10.3.css"
}
ResourceError: {
    "errorCode": 2,
    "errorString": "Connection closed",
    "url": "https://www.hawaiifun.org/reservation/common/datepicker_availability.css"
}
clicked on calendar
ResourceError: {
    "errorCode": 2,
    "errorString": "Connection closed",
    "url": "https://www.hawaiifun.org/reservation/companyservlet?callback=jQuery19102756042554974556_1444269910798&action=COMMON_AVAILABILITYCHECKJSON&activityid=6130&agencyid=0&blocksonly=false&year_months=2015_10&webbooking=true&hawaiifunbooking=false&agencybooking=false&minavailability=&_=1444269910799"
}
CasperError: Cannot get information from xpath selector: //*[@id="dp1444234738328"]/div/table/tbody/tr[5]/td[3]/a: no elements found.
```

Comment: What PhantomJS version do you have? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: phantomjs --version 1.9.0 ...... casperjs --version 1.1.0-beta3

Comment: 1.9.0 is very old. Try updating to 2.0.0, 1.9.8 or 1.9.7. If you're trying 1.9.7 or below, then you can try to add `--ignore-ssl-errors=true --ssl-protocol=any` as a commandline option (before the script argument).

Answer (score 0):

After running your code, I received the following error:

```
clicked on calendar
CasperError: Cannot get information from xpath selector: //*[@id="dp1444234738328"]/div/table/tbody: no elements found.
  /home/user/phantomjs:/platform/casper.js:1173 in getElementsInfo
  /home/user/phantomjs:/code/casperjs.js:17
  /home/user/phantomjs:/platform/casper.js:2368 in _check
```

By changing your XPath selector to `//*[@class="ui-datepicker-calendar"]/tbody`, I was able to run the program error free.

**Here is the full working program:**

```
var casper = require('casper').create();
var utils = require('utils');
var x = require('casper').selectXPath;

casper.userAgent('Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; rv:2.2) Gecko/20110201');

casper.start('http://www.hawaiifoodtours.com/north-shore-food-tour/');

casper.then(function () {
  // Click on the 1st Result Link
  this.click('#date_a6130');

  this.echo('clicked on calendar');
});

casper.wait(1000, function () {
  casper.capture('theCalendar.png');

  // Updated XPath
  var stuff = casper.getElementsInfo(x('//*[@class="ui-datepicker-calendar"]/tbody'));

  utils.dump(stuff);
});

casper.run();
```

> **Note:** I am using CasperJS 1.1.4 with PhantomJS 2.1.1.